# Cannot implicitly convert string[] to string when splitting

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and I don't understand why this isn't working. I want to split a previously splitted string.

My code is the following:

```
int i;
string s;
string[] temp, temp2;

Console.WriteLine("write 'a-a,b-b,c-c,d-d'";
s = Console.ReadLine();
temp = s.Split(',');

for (i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
    temp2[i] = temp[i].Split('-');
```

I get the following error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string`

I want to end with:

```
temp = {a-a , b-b , c-c , d-d};
temp2 = {{a,a},{b,b},{c,c},{d,d}};
```

Comment: sorry, I am new to c# :)

Comment: Probably not the issue, but you forgot a `)` at the end of the `Console.WriteLine()` line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The result of `string.Split()` is `string[]`, which you should already see by the correct usage when you assign to `string[] temp`. But when you are assigning to the elements of `string[]  temp2`, you are trying to store *arrays of strings* in slots that are meant to only store *strings*, hence the compiler error. Your code could work with a simple change below.

```
string[] temp;
string[][] temp2; // array of arrays 

string s = "a-a,b-b,c-c,d-d";
temp = s.Split(',');

temp2 = new string[temp.Length][];

for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
    temp2[i] = temp[i].Split('-');
```

Comment: I get the following error `Use of unassigned local variable 'temp2'`

Answer (score 0):

When you call split, it returns an array of strings. You can't assign string[] to a string variable.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, `Split` returns an array. However, you can split on more than one character at a time. For example,

```
string s = "a,b,c,d-d";
var split = s.Split(new[] {',', '-'});
```

In this case, the `split` array would contain 5 indices, containing "a", "b", "c", "d", and "d".